# Are these files related to the constant 100% CPU usage of `cloudd`?

Tags: icloud, safari, ventura, cpu

On Ventura 13.5.1 `cloudd` is using over 100% CPU constantly.

The only way to stop it that I've discovered is to **reboot**, or to **log out of iCloud** in system settings. After logging in to iCloud again everything's fine, but as soon as I **launch Safari** `cloudd` will start doing the same thing again, and won't stop even after quitting Safari. Turning off specifically Safari for iCloud also seems to give the same result as logging out of iCloud completely.

Launching other iCloud apps like Notes doesn't cause the same excessive surge for `cloudd`. I draw the conclusion that Safari iCloud integration is the cause.

Looking in `~/Library/Containers/Safari/Data/CloudKit/` I see many small directories on the order of magnitude of MBs, while one is in the GBs:

[image: Suspiciously large CloudKit directory]

Is this normal and to be expected, or could it be indicative of a problem?

I've already tried creating a **new local user account** to see if `cloudd`'s behavior is repeated there. It is. That suggests that the problem is not due to some local accidental file structure problem, but more likely with the data synced from the cloud.

Do these directories potentially conain data that has been synced from the cloud, thereby pointing to a possible cause (unending transfers)?

Comment: So far I've been unable to resolve it even after creating a new APFS container and reinstalling the OS. Disabling Safari in iCloud seems the only option.

Comment: Starting to suspect the problem is related to Apple's subpar implementation of *tab groups* — which has been a buggy mess ever since its introduction — considering that more than half of my groups synced to Ventura *have no name whatsoever*. That's not reassuring. At least iOS has stopped deleting all my default group's tabs whenever I open a link in an email...